# React Navigation from 1 page to another not working

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React native for Developing multi page application for iOS & Android.

I have used React Navigation for navigating from 1 page to another. But somehow its not working & give error message.

Here is what I have done so far.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Settings from './Settings';
import Home from './Home';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  SettingScreen: { screen: Settings },
  HomeScreen: { screen: Home }
});

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is the home screen</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

**Settings.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export class Settings extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is the Settings screen</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')} title="Home"/>
      </View>
    )
  }
};

export default Settings;
```

Here is how I am getting error message :

[image]

Any help or hints will be highly appreciated.

**Note :**

- I am trying to run it on iOS
- I have installed React Navigation properly as per the documentation

Comment: I think it's not related to react-navigation. check your packager and make sure your app can connect to packager correctly.

Comment: All was working fine till I added navigation

Comment: which version of react navigation are you using?

Comment: I am not sure I am newbie

Comment: check your `package.json` file and find the version of react navigation

Comment: "react-navigation": "^3.6.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for version > 3 of react navigation, you can confige router like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Settings from './Settings';
import Home from './Home';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SettingScreen: { screen: Settings },
  HomeScreen: { screen: Home }
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Also you can read the documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html)
I hope this can help you.